# Finding XPATH in single nested div statement, when the classname is shared among multiple classnames

Tags: selenium, xpath

So im currently trying to write a test/learn how to use Selenium.  One of the issues I am running in to is that I need to select specfically the number 262 in this nested div.

The issue I ran into is that if I make the xpath `//div[@class='np_amount inline']` that I get multiple results going down the entire page, and if I make it `//div[@class='np_field_amount_etc']`, then I get all three items in the row, and not just the number 262.

However, the initial div class (np_field_amount_etc) is unique.  What xpath command would I write in order to only select the 262 in this series of div's?

```
<div class="np_field_amount_etc">
<div class="np_label inline">Total Calories</div>
<div class="np_amount inline">262 </div>
<div class="np_dv inline">14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, somethings like this:

```
//div[@class='np_field_amount_etc']/div[@class='np_amount inline']
```

is what you want.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  Sorry still a beginner at XPATH's so my questions are pretty basic.